# Я добавляю кастомный тег к дням календаря но он добавляется во всех месяцах к выбраным дням

Tags: javascript

Я добавляю кастомный тег к дням календаря но он добавляется во всех месяцах к выбраным дням

Нужно помочь решить проблему. Есть календарь в котором можно к числу добавлять свой кастомный тег. Но проблема в том, что этот тег добавляется во всех месяцах дней которых я выбрал (в моем случае это числа 1, 10, 12, 25).

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в разных месяцах можно было добавлять этот тег к различным дням.

Сам календарь (Дата пикер) (http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html#install)

Мой код с документации

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    minDate: new Date()
});


var eventDates = [1, 10, 12, 25],
    $picker = $('#calendar'),
    sentences = [];

$picker.datepicker({
    onRenderCell: function (date, cellType) {
        var currentDate = date.getDate();

        // Добавляем вспомогательный элемент, если число содержится в `eventDates`
        if (cellType == 'day' && eventDates.indexOf(currentDate) != -1) {
            return {
                html: currentDate + '<span class="dp-note"></span>'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял Вам необходимо добавлять эти теги только в определенном месяце, а проверку на месяц Вы не добавили.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    // Добавить свой контент во все ячейки с датой 31 декабря.
    onRenderCell: function (date, cellType) {
        if (cellType == 'day' && date.getDate() == 31 && date.getMonth() == 11) {
            return {
                classes: '-ny-',
                html: 'Новый год!'
            }
        }
    }
})
```